# Spring AOP not working when using as a compiled jar in a different project

Tags: java, spring, java-8, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a working AOP (when using inside the project it is written in) but when I build this project (maven install), and use that JAR in another project, and try to use the `@TimedLog` annotation, nothing happens. I try to breakpoint into it, but it doesn't reach there.

It looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TimedLog {
    boolean shouldAttachMethodArgs() default false;
    boolean shouldAttachReturnValue() default false;
    String message() default "";
}
```

This is the actual Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MethodExecutionAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(timedLogVar)")
    public void annotationPointCutDefinition(TimedLog timedLogVar) {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void atExecution() {}

    @Around(value = "annotationPointCutDefinition(timedLogVar) && atExecution()", argNames = "joinPoint,timedLogVar")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, TimedLog timedLogVar) throws Throwable {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        Object returnValue = joinPoint.proceed();
        stopwatch.stop();

        log.info(String.format("test message %s", stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

An implementation of it would be:

```
@TimedLog
void testDefaultValues() throws InterruptedException {
    int sleepTimeInMillis = 200;
    log.info("Resting for {} millis", value("sleepTimeInMillis", sleepTimeInMillis));
    Thread.sleep(sleepTimeInMillis);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<!-- AOP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.13</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

From what you can see here, this is an AOP that decorates a method and logs its runtime.

I've been struggling with it for a while now, and would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

EDIT:
As requested, the full pom.xml of the project that's supposed to use that AOP (it lives `foo.bar.utils`:`utils-common`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
        <groupId>foo.bar.backend</groupId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>backend-logic</artifactId>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-s3-release-repo</id>
            <name>S3 Release Repository</name>
            <url>s3://repository.foobar.com/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-s3-snapshot-repo</id>
            <name>S3 Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>s3://repository.foobar.com/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>foo.bar.backend</groupId>
            <artifactId>backend-contract</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot actuator to expose metrics endpoint -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Micormeter core dependecy  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>foo.bar.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Auth -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

</project>
```

EDIT2:
The implementation that doesn't work (in the different project that's supposed to use the AOP)

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class TestingSomething {

    @TimedLog(message = "test something")
    public void testingSomething() {
        log.info("ololol");
    }

}
```

And the test, testing it:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeSpringConfiguration.class,
        properties = {"server.port=0", "enable.security=true"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class testingSomethingTest {
    @Autowired
    TestingSomething testingSomething;

    @Test
    public void testingLol() {
        testingSomething.testingSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the pom of your project where you are exactly using it??

Comment: Does the other project that uses your jar has aspects enabled through @EnableAspectJAutoProxy or through xml cnfiguration. You mentioned you are using your jar as library, my presumption is that the project that is using this jar has the aspects also enabled ?

Comment: @YatiSawhney I attached the full pom.xml of the project using the jar in the edit

Comment: Don't use an `@Configuration` use a regular component`. The `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` should go on your `SomeSpringConfguration`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the aspects to work you need to enable them. To enable you need to either configure them through xml or through annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```

Through xml:

```
<beans …>
      <!– Enable AspectJ auto-wiring –>
      <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
</beans>
```

When you include your jar into another application, this other application has its own configuration and context. Even if you have enabled the aspect autowiring for your original context you still need to do the same for your new application by one of the two ways pointed above.

If you use the annotation make sure it is within the component scan scope and that it is actualy included into your context.

UPDATE:
do `@Import (MethodExecutionAspect.class)` on your testingSomethingTest to ensure it is component scanned.

Comment: So I did what you suggested (and I also saw this answer in another thread sometime today) and added this annotation on the class that actually logs.
This class is then @Autowired into a test function and called.
And... no luck

Comment: @DorMunis one more time, where did you put the annotation ? And are you sure that the class containing the aspect is comonent scanned ?

Comment: @DorMunis for debug sake place the annotation on your "@SpringBootApplication" or on yurr global configuration class. And in the same class create a method.

"@Bean"
public MethodExecutionAspect methodExecutionAspect() {   return new MethodExecutionAspect()}

Comment: Ops my bad, I meant import on the aspect.

Comment: Did that.. Still nothing... (test so much for your help, much appreciated man. I feel awful that this bloody thing doesn't work)

Comment: I still think you have a problem with component scanning. Mark your Advice with component  autowire it globaly and put a breakpoint in its constructor. If it does not get created then you know.

Comment: Your last update works! I just need to figure out a way to make it more accessible that `@Import`ing the MethodExecutionAspect each time, but that's a different topic, and a much simpler one.
Thanks a lot mate!