# Adding a external Jar is not working, getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have created one AOP Library project which is having Before & After aspect annotation, I had given Maven Build and It's successful. Same Library or annotation I need to use in other service project. I have added library project Jar as a external library in Build Path.
Jar file I am able to see in Referenced Libraries folder.
When I am running Service project I am getting NoClassDefFoundError..

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.**.****.****.aspect.GenesisApiAudit;
import com.**.****.****.aspect.GenesisApiAuditLight;

@RestController
@ComponentScan("com.**.****.****.aspect") //aspect implementation class path
 public class TestAuditController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @GenesisApiAudit
    @GenesisApiAuditLight   
    public String testHello(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "test") String id) {
    
        return "Hello world : ";
    }
}
```

Please see below Logs for Maven Build >>>

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ SpringTestAuditApplication ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\******\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE\SpringTestAuditApplication\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[7,35] package com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[8,35] package com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[14,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GenesisApiAudit
  location: class com.example.demo.controller.TestAuditController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[15,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class GenesisApiAuditLight
  location: class com.example.demo.controller.TestAuditController
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.331 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-09T17:28:03+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project SpringTestAuditApplication: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[7,35] package com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[8,35] package com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[14,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class GenesisApiAudit
[ERROR]   location: class com.example.demo.controller.TestAuditController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/******/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE/SpringTestAuditApplication/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/TestAuditController.java:[15,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class GenesisApiAuditLight
[ERROR]   location: class com.example.demo.controller.TestAuditController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following article
```

Please see the below application Logs >>>>>

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-09-09 20:10:49.356 ERROR 10748 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genesisApiAuditAspect': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect.GenesisApiAuditAspect] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1285) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1200) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringTestAuditApplication.main(SpringTestAuditApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.jp.genesis.audit.aspect.GenesisApiAuditAspect] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

How we can resolve this issue ??

Comment: I think more info are required to chatch your problem. Are you creating the jar with the classpath in the manifest or are you adding the classpath when you're launching the jar? If you provide also your pom.xml, the generated manifest and the command you're using to execute the jar, it could be better.

Comment: Which class can not be found? Can you share the logs and explain the situation in more detail?

Comment: Hi sigur,  Onur, Please check attached logs.

Comment: It should be a maven dependency else it won't be available at runtime.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, Please see this post, Can we use these annotation. Please try to explain me.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299384/spring-aop-not-working-when-using-as-a-compiled-jar-in-a-different-project

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, In previos post ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711205/how-we-can-use-spring-aop-custom-annotation-in-other-spring-boot-project  You replied - You cannot include a spring boot jar as a regular jar in another project. It has a different structure (internally) and thus no classes will be found. Put the annotation and aspect in a separate regular jar and use in both projects. So How we can achieve this ??

Comment: As stated add the jar as a dependency in the pom NOT as a dependency in your project structure as that will only make it known to the IDE **not** when building or running the application outside of your IDE.